# When do I need any other directives for Angular reactive forms other than [formControl]?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms

Although I have been using Angular reactive forms since the release of Angular 2, I have consistently used all available directives in my work: `formGroup`, `formGroupName`, `formControl`, `formControlName` and `formArrayName`.

And today I thought, why use them all, if we can use only `[formControl]="formControl"`? At first glance, if we use only `[formControl]="formControl"`, it greatly simplifies working with Angular reactive forms. Especially when using nested forms, as well as when using the form array. Is there a scenario when I will lack other directives?

**Update**: I almost did not work with Angular dynamic forms, probably they will demand all available directives. Is this the only scenario?

Answer (score 0):

FormControl is used very rarely in real world app, as far as I have worked with Angular, but all other we use very frequently

**formGroup directive** is used in template when form fields are grouped in component, check it here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective

**formControlName** is used in template to bind individual input fields to a form control of form group, this is used with formGroup directive

**formGroupName** is used in template to bind to a nested form group inside parent form group, check it here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName

**formArrayName** is used in template inside formGroup directive to bind to form array of form group in component, check it here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName